# Use WP7 camera to read text

Tags: windows-phone-7, text, camera

I need to point camera at some text and fill some textboxes with text it found. Its provided in bing search in wp7. Can i use such functionality in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Mango WP SDK has a feature called [Bing Vision](http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/bing-vision-api.html). That's exactly what you want. It is available starting from WP 7.5 though.

Or you can try [Project Hawaii SDK](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/hawaii/), it has OCR capabilities too, and is available starting WP 7.1, but is more of research than stable API.

Comment: Both cant even recognise numbers.. :(

Comment: Didn't tried it myself but according to Hawaii documentation:Optical Character Recognition (OCR) Service takes a photographic image that contains some text and returns the text. For example, given a JPEG image of a road sign, the service would return the text of the sign. So I presume it reads numbers too

Comment: I will take your word for it, though it is a bit surprizing:  I know for sure that Bing itself is using it. Probably, as usual, MS guys aren't exposing the most juicy SDK parts, just leaving us, poor developers, in the darkness till better times

Comment: Bing cant recognize the texts i want too..The thing i want-is to read some texts from check. There is barcode on it, so that OCR thinks that parts of barcode are text and the actual text remains unrecognized. I'll try http://notanothercodeblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/google-goggles-api.html later.